# Website grabber with support for resuming the download

Tags: windows, download-manager, http

I want a perfect website grabbing software, which should run on Windows 8 32 bit.

I need to grab a website gradually. I mean grabbing 5 or 10 pages daily. But it needs to start where I left yesterday. So if a website have 50 pages and I grabbed 5 pages today, it needs to start grabbing from page 6.

Currently I am using [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/), but it is scaning from beginning at each startup.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I used HTTrack, but according to [this](http://mytechquest.com/windows/httrack-website-copier-lets-you-browse-your-favorite-websites-offline-on-your-desktop/) article, as well as [these](http://forum.httrack.com/readmsg/18767/18766/index.html) official support forum entries, you can accomplish what you want. The [docs](http://www.httrack.com/html/faq.html#Q10a) suggest the same.